# Windows 2010 20H2 Update fails with a rollback

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v20h2

Windows 10 update 20H2 update fails everytime with a rollback.

Some of the error codes I receive:

- `0xc1900101`
- `*FAILED* [8024000C] Method failed [CAgentUpdateManager::ManufactureHistoryEventForOSUpgrade:14710]`
- `NET HELPMSG 2182`

I have used the following tool in the past to get update working, but this time it did not make any difference:
[Reset Windows Update Tool](https://www.wureset.com/)

I even downloaded the latest version of Windows 10 that include 20H2 via the download tool and try to update using that, and it resulted in the same issue:
[Windows 10 Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

How can I debug/fix the update?
It is frustrating wasting hours due to multiple restarts, just to rollback to before the update. And then to go though it again a few days later due to Windows trying to update again...

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the problem in the following log file:
`C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\setupact.log`
[Log files that are created when you upgrade to a new version of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-windows-9ec8aa31-0cc1-a0b2-2d98-e9c6714349b9)

[Log files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/log-files)

I searched for `Rollback` and found the following line:

`2021-02-21 12:54:23, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: Rollback Enabled via scenario detection.`

About a screen up I found the following errors:

```
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SdbUtils::CheckForMigShim (1555):   Error generating migxml for QualcommRadioDriverMigrationShim / : [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SdbUtils::CheckAppQueryResult (516):   Error getting migshim info: [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::MatchingInfoSdbDataSource::ApplyEntries (284):   Error checking query result 2840808: [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::MatchingInfoSdbDataSource::ApplyDataSource (250):   Error applying upgrade block entries: [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Info                  CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::WicaEngine::CheckComponentResult (2209):   Swallowing error [0x800700e8] for [DatasourceWuDriver].
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::WicaEngine::RunComponents (1348):   RunDataSources Failed: [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Info                  CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::WicaEngine::RunComponents (1366):   Engine finished.
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::WicaFactory::DoWicaRun (366):   Failed to run engine: [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::ScanInternal (285):   WicaRun failed: [0x80070490].[gle=0x80070490]
2021-02-21 12:54:23, Info                  CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::StartScan (159):   Start Scan Done
```

In the top lone I noticed `QualcommRadioDriverMigrationShim`, and the only Qualcomm device I have is the build in network card.

I did the following to remove the Qualcomm device and driver:

- I disabled the build in LAN in the BIOS settings. (I don't know if the rest is needed, but I did it to be safe)
- I uninstalled the driver with Add/Remove programs.
- Lastly I remove the drivers from Device Manager (View -> Enable `Show Hidden Devices`). Right click on the applicable devices, and select `Uninstall Device`.

The update worked perfectly after that.

Comment: Good find and good job.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already used it, **[SetupDiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag)** is a useful diagnostic tool from Microsoft for troubleshooting upgrade impediments and failures. It doesn't find failure signatures every time, but *most* of the time it does.